# ffmpeg audio conversion in flutter

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, mp3, wav

I would like to get data from audio file based on microphone input (both Android and iOS), currently I'm using audioplayers and recordMp3 to record the microphone input. This results in a mp3 file with a local file path. In order to use the audio data, I want an uncompressed format like WAV. Would ffmpeg help with this conversion ? I want to eventually use this data for visualization.

Comment: Sure, `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.wav`. But why not originally capture the audio as WAV instead of MP3 if it is WAV that you want? Or why can you not use the MP3 for visualization?

Comment: mp3 is compressed format which cannot be used for visualization of a waveform .... hmmm that's what I am getting from the reading

Answer (score 0):

## MP3 to WAV

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.wav
```

Note that any encoding artifacts in the MP3 will be included in the WAV.

## Piping from `ffmpeg` to your visualizer

I'm assuming you need WAV/PCM because your visualizer only accepts that format and does not accept MP3. You can create a WAV file as shown in the example above, but if your visualizer accepts a pipe as input you can avoid creating a temporary file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f wav - | yourvisualizer …
```

## Using `ffmpeg` for visualization

See examples at [How do I turn audio into video (that is, show the waveforms in a video)?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/9697/1760)

Comment: how can we use ffmpeg in flutter